# How to get last 5 rows?

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql, sql-limit

I'm trying to get the list of only the last five rows from the table. I've already tried with `limit 5` but no luck .

Here is the method

```
@Transactional
public List<Poll> findAllLimit5() {
    return em.createQuery("select a from Poll a ", Poll.class).getResultList();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults-int-

Comment: Thanks for the link i tried with **setMaxResults** it worked.

Comment: How do you know which 5 it will receive?

Comment: in the select query i added **ORDER BY a.id_poll DESC ** so it will receive the last 5 rows and if I did not added that by default it will receive the first 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified method

```
@Transactional
public List<Poll> findAllLimit5() {
    return em
            .createQuery("select a from Poll a ORDER BY a.id_poll DESC ",
                    Poll.class).setMaxResults(5).getResultList();

}
```